# Polya-Vinogradov inequality over non-consecutive integers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $N$ and $a$ be positive integers. Consider the Kronecker symbol $\left( \frac{n}{m} \right)$, which is a character modulo $m$. I have seen it several times that 'by Polya-Vinogradov inequality', we have
$$
\sum_{0<n\leq Y, n \equiv a (N)} \left(\frac{n}{m}\right) \ll \sqrt m \log m.
$$

However, the sum is not over consecutive integers, so I think this is not a trivial fact. How can I prove this?

Comment: Is the implied constant supposed to be independent of $N$?  If so, then it seems like you have a problem with $m=N$.  If not, then it seems like you can get a bound of size something like $N^{3/2} \sqrt m \log m$ by using orthogonality relations to select $a \pmod N$.

Comment: Erick Wong // What is 'orthogonality relations'?

Comment: Erick is suggesting writing $$\sum_{\substack{n\le y \\ n\equiv a\pmod N}} \bigg( \frac nm \bigg) = \frac1{\phi(N)} \sum_{\chi\pmod N} \overline\chi(a) \sum_{n\le y} \chi(n) \bigg( \frac nm \bigg);$$ the inner sum is a character sum (of a character modulo $mN$) over an interval.

Comment: Martin // Thank you, Martin. Could you let me know the reason why the equation hold, or any reference?

Comment: Martin // Now I understand. Thank you.